# Graceful rearrangement of the interface on a netbook?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Hi,

I do a lot of my stuff, including answering m.se questions, on a netbook with a ten-inch screen and 1024-by-768 resolution. I'm currently using Opera 10.61 build 6430 on a Fedora 8 (please spare me the requests to upgrade :P), and the current interface has a slight problem for me, which I shall illustrate with this screenshot:

[image: screwed interface]

As can be seen, the "ASK QUESTION" link, probably due to my small screen size, has dropped down below the other links. It would be merely a minor annoyance if it were not for the fact that I couldn't click the blasted thing either.

Is it possible that the CSS can be tweaked a *tiny* bit to accommodate? I didn't have this problem back when the site was still a Beta site.

Thanks for any attention.

Comment: Is this perhaps the same issue as in http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/979/new-design-ask-question-overlaps-background ?

Comment: @Isaac: it doesn't actually overlap, and I don't know what he's seeing on his screen so I'm not sure if we have in fact the same problem. In any event, the question was marked `status-completed`, and the OP there has voiced his approval, so I suppose his was a different sort of problem. If this is deemed a dupe, please feel free to close.

Comment: It looks like the text on your machine is showing up in Bitstream Vera Serif, which is the default serif font on most Linux distributions. This font is wider than the ones specified in the CSS, which is why the navigation bar is wrapping to the next line. I can reproduce this on my Linux machine if I go into Firebug and prepend `"Bistream Vera Serif"` to the `font-face` list.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, I am not that well-versed in the nuances of fonts, so I didn't know what other detail had to be appended to my question.

Comment: M.: I didn't actually think it was a dupe, but seeing your screenshot I thought I might have actually understood what he was talking about in the other post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put in a fix for this, it will be in the next deployment.

Answer (score 2):

In the spirit of open source (yes, I know StackExchange isn't), here's a patch for Jin. In the CSS block for `#header #hmenus`, replacing `width: 655px` with `display: table` fixes the issue, even with the "comically" wide Linux fonts. It doesn't seem to change the layout in any other way. I found the solution [on this page about horizontal centering in CSS](http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/Horizontal-Centering#block-no-width), which also has details about hacks for supporting IE using conditional comments.

[image: This is a screenshot.]

Comment: thanks for the tip! i ended up using padding instead, since this is a fixed width parent container. I prefer solving it in pure css instead of having IE conditional codes just for this 1 particular case.